# Why only main.rs can declare mod?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

```
main.rs
main2.rs
file1.rs
src/something.rs
Cargo.toml
```

on `main.rs`, doing `mod file1` works, but doing `mod file1` on `main2.rs` leads to

```
file not found for module `file1`
```

Why only `main.rs` can declare sibling files with `mod`?

Comment: Probably just for simplicity and for keeping the same convention. You can *define* a few modules inside one file (the root of them is this file), or you can *define* modules in separate files (in this case the root of them is the parent module's entry point - i.e. `mod.rs` for arbitrary modules, or `main.rs`/`lib.rs` for a top-most modules)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New modules can be declared from both `main.rs` and `lib.rs`. The first is used for binary crates, the latter - for libraries. It's important to note that if a package has both files, then it will have two crates with the same name (one library and one binary). You can also have multiple binary crates, if you define the `crate roots` (explained below) in `src/bin` - each file will be treated as a separate binary crate. This is explained in detail in [the rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-01-packages-and-crates.html).

These two files are special - they are called *crate roots*, because they form a tree-like structure. Each module should be part of it. You cannot define a module outside that tree. This is again explained [in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-02-defining-modules-to-control-scope-and-privacy.html).

Thus in order to be able to define a new module from within `main2.rs`, it either has to be a `crate root` - i.e. it has to have a `main()` and be located in `/src/bin/main2.rs` or it has to be part of the module-tree, descending from some of the crate roots.